# .Net 6 Swagger how to display enums as strings

Tags: c#, .net, swagger, asp.net-core-6.0

[swagger example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2Npk.png)

Hello! I am trying to add enums as parameters for my swagger endpoint but they are being displayed as integers. On the old .net there was option for swagger `option.DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings();` but I don't have it on the .net 6.
[program code example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gwJf.png)

I try adding `options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());` but still not showing my enums as strings.

Comment: You add NewtonSoft support but add the System.Text.Json converter. The combination feels weird.

Comment: This was one of the suggestions I found and tried it. Still doesn't work..

Answer (score 14):

I found the [same issue](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1269#issuecomment-1042722294) here, and I test the workaround mentioned in the question in my side and it worked for me.

In `Program.cs`,

Append `.AddJsonOptions(options => { options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter()); });` behind `builder.Services.AddControllers()`

The code should look like:

```
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers()
    .AddJsonOptions(options => { options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter()); });
```

[image]